# Why is this tail-call optimized method not recognized as such by the Scala compiler?

Tags: scala, tail-call-optimization

This simple regex implementation ([scastie here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eJItQOB2QAuXxGhxZku31w)) does not compile, where I expected it to. The error is at line 14, where an intermediate recursive call is interpreted as to break the `@tailrec` requirement. While this intermediate recursive call is indeed not in tail-call position, the actual last call of the expression *is*, making the complete expression tail-call optimized.

This line of reasoning can be illustrated by aliasing the intermediate recursive call, turning it into an 'arbitrary' call. When the this call is aliased by `aliasMatches`, the code compiles and executes as expected.

Why doesn't the compiler accepts the non-aliased implementation? Is this a practical limitation, or is there something wrong with the reasoning above? Is there a way to coax the compiler in accepting the first version (other than a complete accumulator-rewrite) that I'm missing?

(using Scala 2.13.5)

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def matches(input: String, pattern: String): Boolean = {

    @tailrec
    def matchesRemainder(remainder: Seq[Char], remainingPattern: Seq[Char]): Boolean =
        (remainder, remainingPattern) match {
            case (Seq(), Seq()) => true
            case (Seq(_@_*), Seq()) => false

            case (Seq(), Seq(_, '*', _@_*)) => true
            case (Seq(), Seq(_@_*)) => false
                                                        \\ vvvv error vvvv
            case (Seq(_, rs@_*), Seq('.', '*', xs@_*)) => matchesRemainder(rs, remainingPattern) ||
                matchesRemainder(remainder, xs)
            case (Seq(r, rs@_*), Seq(p, '*', xs@_*)) => (r == p && aliasMatches(rs, remainingPattern)) ||
                matchesRemainder(remainder, xs)

            case (Seq(_, rs@_*), Seq('.', ps@_*)) => matchesRemainder(rs, ps)
            case (Seq(r, rs@_*), Seq(p, ps@_*)) => r == p && matchesRemainder(rs, ps)
        }

    def aliasMatches(remainder: Seq[Char], p: Seq[Char]): Boolean =
        matchesRemainder(remainder, p)

    matchesRemainder(input, pattern)
}
```

Comment: Scala 1.13.5 doesn't exist

Comment: The last expression is not the recursive call but the call to `||`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez then why does it compile when using the alias? doesn't `||` evaluate into its last argument if the first fails, making that last argument the tail-call?

Comment: @cchantep darn, oops, you're right, I overlooked my typo (twice) apparently. Apologies, I'll correct it.

Comment: @JoostPapendorp uhm you are right, but I am not sure if the compiler is smart enough to figure that out; it probably is _(it is at least smarter than me)_. - In any case, if you have two recursive calls in the same block even if the last one is in tail position the first one is not which implies that your code could indeed blow up the stack.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez "I am not sure if the compiler is smart enough to figure that out" --> I was afraid of that. Oh well. 
"even if the last one is in tail position the first one is not which implies that your code could indeed blow up the stack." --> Correct, it does (hence my comment on accu-rewrite).

Comment: It compiles when using the alias because the compiler doesn't see that the alias is a recursive call.  You could do a partial accumulator rewrite by reifying the `matchesRemainder(remainder, xs)` into an object and passing a list (normally empty) of those objects; then in situations where the match fails (take care with the `&&` in the last case) you fall back to the alternative.

Comment: But if you're looking for a regular expression implementation that's amenable to a tail recursive implementation, I'd strongly suggest building a tree representation of the regular expression and using Brzozowski derivative.

Comment: @LeviRamsey so you're saying the first error is intentional after all and partial tail recursion is explicitly caught and banned by the compiler? That means the alias-masking is merely removing the tools.
Creating a list of lazy objects is a nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify it a little bit, to see the problem more clearly.

```
    @tailrec
    def foo(x: Int): Boolean = x == 0 || foo(x-1) || foo(x-2)
```

This does not compile, because it cannot eliminate recursion completely: `foo(x-1)` has to return control back to the caller, so in can evaluate the result and either return it, or call `foo(x-2)`.
Tail recursion can only happen when the result of the recursive call is directly returned right away, without the control returning to the caller.

Now why does this compile?

```
   def bar(x: Int) = foo(x) 
   @tailrec
   def foo(x: Int): Boolean = x == 0 || bar(x-1) || foo(x-2)
```

Well, that's just cheating :) The compiler doesn't expect you to be that cunning, it has no way of knowing that `bar` is just going to call `foo`, so it has to trust you on that.

Basically `@tailrec` can only detect the immediate recursion if you try to mask it ... well, you will succeed :)

Remove `|| foo(x-2)` from the above – it'll stop compiling, and tell you there is no recursion. Even though it is now a perfectly tail-recursive function, it will not be able to optimize it.

It's not a golden bullet. Here's another quirk:

```
    @tailrec
    def foo(x: => Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
       x.recoverWith { case _ => foo(x) }
       foo(Future(1))
    }
```

This *is* tail-recursive, but it will refuse to compile, because it does not realize that the first call to `foo` doesn't actually happen inside the outer `foo`.

Comment: Thank you, that was really informative. The compiler only accepts full tail-recursion, even when it can optimize for partial. I was aware that using the alias was cheating, but now I also know why.

Comment: I don't think "partial tail recursion" is a thing. Tail recursion means O(1) stack. So, it either is or isn't, no "partials".